# Find field and replace content of field with another file content

Tags: shell-script, sed, regular-expression

I have two files:

**File1:**

```
not_keyword: 'something'
keyword: 'condition'
another_not_keyword: 'something'
```

**File2:**

```
condition 1 condition 2 condition 3
```

I would like to find all occurrences of `keyword` in **File1** and replace its content *(condition)* with the content of **File2**.

Desired output in this case:

```
not_keyword: 'something'
keyword: 'condition 1 condition 2 condition 3'
another_not_keyword: 'something"
```

Comment: Should the non-occurrences of `keyword` in  File1 be kept or should they be removed?

Comment: Good question @PauloTomé! I've edited the original question. They should be kept. TY!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

How about

```
$ awk -F': ' '
    BEGIN{OFS=FS; getline value < "File2"} $1 == "keyword" {$2 = q value q} 1
  ' q="'" File1
not_keyword: 'something'
keyword: 'condition 1 condition 2 condition 3'
another_not_keyword: 'something'
```

Comment: Works perfectly! Any change the changes can be done directly in the file itself?

Comment: @t988GF if you have a sufficiently recent version of GNU awk (`gawk`) then yes - by adding `-i inplace` to the command line options

Comment: Good call. Turns out I'm running on a system where I can't install anything. gawk seems recent enough but unfortunately I won't be able to use it. I'll mark the answer as correct, since it does in fact do what I need, even though if someone could provide an answer with standard coreutils I would appreciate it.